# Does SO provide daily metrics on questions, answers, etc?

Tags: support, statistics

Does SO (and other SE sites) provide metrics or ideally charts of how many questions and answers are posted per hour/day/week? It would be interesting to see how this varies day to day, at weekends, etc.

Comment: https://data.stackexchange.com/tutorial

Comment: @rene thanks but I was more asking if some pages already exist displaying key metrics

Comment: here you go: https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/1429976#graph

Comment: With the [Site Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) privilege, you have access to some graphs that can show some of that.

Comment: Thanks @rene I haven't used `data` before and hadn't realised it could provide charting as well as raw data.

Answer (score 8):

[Site Analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/site-analytics) will give you the data you want.

Access to site analytics is a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/site-analytics) granted at 25k reputation.