# How fast do questions on Stack Overflow get added?

Tags: discussion, statistics

Basically, what is the rate at which questions are asked on SO, on average? Because when I look away for a minute, a ton more questions are posted.

Comment: @Ivar I don't think we should close OP's question against that post. Duplication is determined by answers, not questions. What was true in 2016 is no longer true in 2021 and vice versa. There are no answers on the proposed duplicate that would indicate its relevance.

Comment: @OlegValter The numbers might have changed, but the answer there also points to the source of those numbers, which is still accurate.

Comment: @Ivar so has this one with current info, with a pointer to the original answer, and with your comment about the query - we do not have a requirement to close against the first asked question.

Comment: you may also find this interesting (look for comments on the question) - I knew I saw a similar request fairly recently: [Does SO provide daily metrics on questions, answers, etc?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/408891/11407695)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As shown in [All Sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites#questionsperday) sorted by questions per day, StackOverflow has about 5.8K questions asked per day (i.e., about 4 per minute on average).

A very similar question of [How many questions are posted per day on Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146412/562482) on Meta SE has an answer which states

> 5,378 questions per day on average over the last two weeks

as the text to the "All Sites" link I provided above. This answer was from Sep. 9, 2012 (i.e., almost 9 years ago) but, interestingly, the value is not very much different now. Also, since the answer states this value was from over two weeks, it's likely the current period of time is either the same, or at least not too much different. Note the answer mentions the [API's /info](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/info#filter=default&site=stackoverflow&run=true) monitor that you can use to get basically real time data on `questions_per_minute`.

Comment: Over what time period? The entire life time (nearly 13 years)? The last month?

Comment: I think over the last day

Comment: @Leo: That would fit with the expected approx. 8,000 questions on a weekday.

Comment: @PeterMortensen That is a good question. Unfortunately, I don't know what algorithm is used, but I suspect based on values near the end of the list that give fractional parts for the # of questions per day that it's at least several days. However, I doubt it's the entire life time, with it more likely being something like a month (as you suggested), a few months or perhaps a year.

Comment: @Leo The smaller sites show the # of questions per day with fractional parts, so the period of time at least for them must be more than just the last day. Thus, for consistency, I suspect that the value for SO is the same period of time and, as such, also over more than just a day.

Comment: @PeterMortensen FYI, I just found & added details about a Meta SE post which indicates that, at least 9 years ago, it seems the Sites link used a period of 2 weeks to get the # of questions per day.

Comment: [This query](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/628992/questions-per-day) can be used to see how many questions are asked on every individual date.